# elastcsearch : is it possible to emit overlapping tokens with the pattern tokenizer?

Tags: elasticsearch

Working with elasticsearch, I want to set up an analyzer to emit overlapping tokens given an input string, a little bit like the edge Ngrams tokenizer.
Given the input

```
a/b/c
```

I would like the analyzer to produce tokens

```
a a/b a/b/c
```

I tried the pattern tokenizer with the following setup:

```
settings: {
  analysis: {
    tokenizer: {
      "my_tokenizer": {
        "type": "pattern",
        "pattern": "^(.*)(/|$)",
        "group": 1
       }
...
```

However it doesn't output all the matching sequences and because it is greedy will only output

```
a/b/c
```

Is there a way I could do this with another combination of builtin tokenizers/filters/analyzers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your values format, you could use a [path hierarchy](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html#analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer) tokenizer.

Tried with the analyze API :

```
GET _analyze?tokenizer=path_hierarchy&text=a/b/c
```

Output was quite close to what you want :

```
{
   "tokens": [
      {
         "token": "a",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 1,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "a/b",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 3,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      },
      {
         "token": "a/b/c",
         "start_offset": 0,
         "end_offset": 5,
         "type": "word",
         "position": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

Give it a try, and let us know :)

Comment: It's strange, that exact request gives me tokens "a", "b" and "c" but the documentation agrees with your answer ; my elasticsearch version must be borked, will have to upgrade...

Comment: OK, defining a custom analyzer using a PathHierarchy tokenizer works. Thanks!